# invalid date format

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate

I am getting date as string in following format:
 **2012-01-15T08:29:47.000Z**

I want to convert this string to nsdate but I am not able to use correct format. I am using **yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.sTZD** but it doesn't seems to be working. can some one please help me with correct date format.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Unicode date format list](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns) (to which Apple adheres, minus a bug or two), the format for `2012-01-15T08:29:47.000Z` should be this (untested):

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'
```